# SignalR Update Chart not working as expected

Tags: angular, signalr, asp.net-core-webapi

Iam using Net Core api and angular, and I have one dashboard here There are some charts. I open this page with two different user. And when I change in database something,from signalr api both changed data and unchanged data are coming like below in console.log. In db I changed 3 to 2 last second element only.

```
  home.component.ts:2153 -1,1,31.01.2020,-1,2,-1
2 home.component.ts:2153 -1,1,31.01.2020,-1,3,-1
2 home.component.ts:2153 -1,1,31.01.2020,-1,2,-1
  home.component.ts:2153 -1,1,31.01.2020,-1,3,-1
  home.component.ts:2153 -1,1,31.01.2020,-1,2,-1
2 home.component.ts:2153 -1,1,31.01.2020,-1,3,-1
  home.component.ts:2153 -1,1,31.01.2020,-1,2,-1
```

In core part in controller I call this. It call one method and it returns data

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("Charts")]
public IActionResult Charts(int refShare, int sicil)
{
    var timerManager = new TimerManeger(() => _hub.Clients.All.SendAsync(refShare.ToString(), new { type = "chart", data= _repo.SharingDashboard(refShare, sicil) }));
    return Ok(new { Message = "Charts Completed" });
}
```

In angular part

```
this._hub= new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder().withUrl(Url.url.signalR.getMessages, {
      skipNegotiation: true,
      transport: signalR.HttpTransportType.WebSockets
}).build();
this._hub.start().
    then(()=>console.log("Connection Started")).
    catch(err=>console.log(err));
this._hub.on(this.refShare.toString(),(data)=>{
    this.RealTimeDahboard(data.data)
});
this.startHttpRequest();
```

When I write `console.log` in `RealTimeDahboard()` function above result comes. So my chart is always changing. It happens when I open with two user at the same time. If I open one user, it works normally.
What can be the reason ?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This provably happens because when your second user connects to the hub and calls your method, it instantiates the `new TimerManeger()` and so you have 2 instances calling the hub method `_hub.Clients.All.SendAsync()`.

So if for example you will have 10 users, you will receive 10 times the data each timer tick.

What you doing here with signalr is not the right thing to do. When you client connects to the hub, it should not trigger a `http` method. I would recommend just to add your clients to a chart group, and your timer service send the updated chart data to all clients connected to that group.

I have a GitHub project that also refresh chart data in real time using SignalR and you can see how I approached your similar problem there. You can have a look [here](https://github.com/Kiril1512/SignalRDemo).

I have a similar project with charts on GitHub and you can see how it is done.

Comment: Even they create two timers, why don't take same data. why one of them take previous data ? they have same request to repository

Comment: @pc_coder this is another question. First of all you should fix the architecture issue of your code so you use SignalR correctly. Then if you issue continues, just add a new question to that topic and this provably will not be related to SignalR.